# How to change the Scope of a product system attribute like Status from website to global - Magento 2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, eav, scope, eav-attributes

In my Magento 2.2.5 store, how can I change the scope of one of the product system attributes e.g. `Status`. There is a `is_global` field in the table `catalog_eav_attribute`. Do I have to change `is_global` field value, or there is any other work around possible for this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved:**

You can update the scope of the products attribute in Magento 2.2 by navigating to

**Admin => Stores => Attributes => Products => Select Attribute => Scope Drop Down => Select Global => Save Attribute**

Thats all, ;)